# Layout folder to support different devices screens

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, directory

By following [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) tutorial, I created 3 different layout folders (over default layout folder):

- layout-large
- layout-small
- layout-xlarge

In this way, some screens do not fit as I want.
For example, Nexus s, Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4 preview seem to use the default layout, but it doesn't fit  well.
Should I create other layout folders, for these devices (and others that I'm maybe forgetting)?

Comment: Just create different drawable folders for images.

Comment: i already have different folder for image.

Comment: different drawable folders like drawable-large-mdpi, drawable-large-xhdpi??

Comment: the identifier large-small-xlarge aren't enough, there are other like smallestwidth etc, go to this site : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: not large, just default folder that create eclipse: hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xdpi,xxhdpi

Answer (score 0):

Nexus s, Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4 are all "normal" sized devices (or large, i'm not sure). So the behaviour you're getting is "correct".

Have you tried to specify layouts according to the smallest width?

Something like layout-sw480dp, this should target the devices you want.

Comment: for now i've replace large, small and xlarge folder (seems to be deprecated) with hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xdpi and xxhdpi, and seems ok